custom tabs hover card on the title web tab
enter image description here
How to make it so that when the text on the hover card tab is too long, it will jump down to the new line using React JS, in my error it has shown ' ... instead of jumping down the line. People help me with 
I tried to find the documents online but couldn't find  them
